# ¿Como capturar datos de notificación en un textview?

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en una app de notificación, y me gustaría  capturar la notificación recibida en un `textView` desde otra `activity`, pero siempre me llega null al abrir la mi notificación ... 
intente de esa forma ..
Mi clase de Servicio

```
private void enviarNotificacion(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String title = data.get("title");
    String body = data.get("body");

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Acc";


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("body", body);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = endingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setTicker("Acc ")
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000})
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo("info");
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

mi clase Main Activity

```
 txtTitulo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulotxt);
    txtNotificacion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNotificacion);

    Intent bundle= getIntent();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Titulo = bundle.getStringExtra("title");
        MensajeNotificacion = bundle.getStringExtra("body");
        txtTitulo.setText(Titulo);
        txtNotificacion.setText(MensajeNotificacion);

    }
```

NO se porque me llega siempre null , alguna ayuda por favor... 
Gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿que es "endingIntent." en esta linea:  PendingIntent pendingIntent = endingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);      ?

Comment: es un objeto que me permite de lanzar el intent al otro activity

Comment: debe ser "PendingIntent" no "endingIntent", además revisa las consideraciones que agrego en mi respuesta, no debes tener problema para recibir los datos y agregarlos a tus TextView, saludos.

Comment: si fue asi , solo era un error de copy/paste cuando formulaba la pregunta pero sigue igual ,sin popular la notificacion

Comment: El código para recibir la información debe estar en MainActivity. @ApseSony

Comment: claro , esta en mi MainActivity @Elenasys

Comment: La única razón por la cual no se reciban los datos es que inicialmente los datos no se encuentren en RemoteMessage @ApseSony, dentro de enviarNotificacion() imprime los datos de  String title = data.get("title");
    String body = data.get("body"); y comenta.

Comment: @Elenasys me lo puedes explicar  en elgun codigo porfavor porque me parece que ya lo hice lo que me estas diciendo ... no entiendo bien

Answer (score 0):

Noto un problema, el `PendingIntent` debe ser declarado de esta forma:

```
  //PendingIntent pendingIntent = endingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,0);
```

No debes tener problema en recibir los valores del bundle, pero estos van a ser recibidos cuando des clic a la notificación ya que el `PendingIntent` tiene relacionado el `Intent` que contiene los datos.

**Importante saber que los datos únicamente pueden ser recibidos dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`.**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtTitulo=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titulotxt);
        txtNotificacion=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNotificacion);

        Intent bundle= getIntent();
        if (bundle != null) {
           String Titulo = bundle.getStringExtra("title");
            String MensajeNotificacion = bundle.getStringExtra("body");
            txtTitulo.setText(Titulo);
            txtNotificacion.setText(MensajeNotificacion);            

        }

}
```

---

De acuerdo a las consideraciones anteriores, la única razón por la cual no se reciban los datos es que inicialmente los datos no se encuentren en `RemoteMessage` y por lo tanto no puedan obtenerse, verifica que aquí se obtienen los valores correctamente:

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
String title = data.get("title");
String body = data.get("body");
...
...
```